# How to store array and pointer value inputs in assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86-64

If a function has input of array and other type of value such as

```
f(arr[],n,&a,&b)
```

Then, how can I store the inputs?

If I store them like

```
pushq %rbp
movq %rsp, %rbp
pushq %rbp
```

Then, what is the address of the inputs?

I think

```
16(rbp)=n 
24(rbp)=&a
32(rbp)=&b 
40(rbp)... 40(rbp,n,8)=arr.
```

Is it true?

Comment: Arrays are passed as a pointer to their first element. The array itself can be anywhere in memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main 64-bit ABIs are

- [Microsoft x64 Calling Convention](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235286.aspx)
- [SYS V ABI](https://people.freebsd.org/~obrien/amd64-elf-abi.pdf)

both use registers for the first four (4) arguments if they are of the class *INTEGER*.
Pointers and integral types are of such class.
Arrays decay into pointers<sup>1</sup>, pointers are passed as 64-bit integers at the ABI level.
So is like the function takes four integers.

For Windows programming `arr[], n, &a, &b` are passed in *RCX*, *RDX*, *R8* and *R9*.
For Linux programming `arr[], n, &a, &b` are passed in *RDI*, *RSI*, *RDX* and *RCX*.

---

To access the array, you need to do pointer arithmetic.  Supposing *RDI* holds the pointer to the array (read pointer to the first element of the array):

```
mov eax, DWORD [rdi]        ;access arr[0]
mov ebx, DWORD [rdi + 04h]  ;access arr[1]
```

The var `a` and `b` can be accessed as normal pointers (assuming Linux ABI)

```
mov eax, DWORD [rdx]        ;Read a into eax
mov DWORD [rcx], eax        ;b = a
```

The argument `n` can be read directly from *RSI*.

---

Note that you still have some requirement for the stack, particularly on Windows.
You can read the relevant ABI for more information.

---

<sup>1</sup> Not strictly a correct use of the "decay" verb as found in the C++ specs.

Comment: Thank you for your help for this and the next question. I am supernew in system programming, thus I have no idea how to check what's going on. Your suggestion using debugger was great hint since I do not understand purpose of debugger.