# x86-64 Linux NASM. Function parameter passing of type int array declared as a function in C++ file

Tags: c++, linux, assembly, stack, function-parameter

I tried using this advice for this problem

[For Linux programming arr[], n, &a, &b are passed in RDI, RSI, RDX and RCX.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40507639/how-to-store-array-and-pointer-value-inputs-in-assembly)

and the output of the program doesn't sum up the integers in the array properly. It outputs a large number that is obviously wrong.

The two files found below were modified from the original 32-bit version found here. http://mcs.uwsuper.edu/sb/224/Intro/c_asm.html

What I want is to compile an assembly file that calls a function parameter in a C++ file called `array.cpp` and then link the resulting object file `array.o` with `g++`.

The problem I'm having has to do with either the passing of the proper registers onto the stack or maybe the number of bytes to add for each offset on the `rsi` register ( I used 8 since each stack element is 64 bits).

It could also be that the `rbp` register isn't properly loaded at the correct offsets of the *array address* and *number of elements* in the array.

```
 mov rcx, [rbp+24]   ; array length
 mov rsi, [rbp+16]    ; array address
```

Anyways, here's the `array.cpp` file and below it is the nasm file, I called it `nasm_cpp.asm`.

They compile, link and run with

```
nasm -f elf64 nasm_cpp.asm -o array.o
g++ -m64 array.cpp array.o
./a.out


#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

extern "C" int array(int a[], int length);   // external ASM procedure

int main()
{
  int a[] = { 10, 10};  // array declaration
  int array_length = 2;                     // length of the array

  int sum = array(a, array_length);          // call of the ASM procedure

  cout << "sum=" << sum << endl;             // displaying the sum
}
```

This is nasm_cpp.asm below

```
;nasm -f elf64 nasm_cpp.asm -o array.o
;g++ -m64 array.cpp array.o
;./a.out
global array               ; required for linker and NASM
section .text              ; start of the "CODE segment"

array: push rbp           
       mov rbp, rsp        ; set up the rBP
       push rcx            ; save used registers
       push rdi
       push rsi

       mov rcx, [rbp+24]   ; array length
       mov rsi, [rbp+16]    ; array address

       xor rax, rax        ; clear the sum value       
lp:    add rax, [rsi]      ; fetch an array element
       add rsi, 8         ; move to another element
       loop lp             ; loop over all elements

       pop rsi             ; restore used registers
       pop rdi
       pop rcx     
       pop rbp
       ret                 ; return to caller
```

Comment: Parameters are passed in registers on x86-64. Google for "SYS V ABI x64"

Comment: Here http://wiki.osdev.org/System_V_ABI it says `Parameters to functions are passed in the registers rdi, rsi, rdx, rcx, r8, r9,`. Is that what you think might solve it? What about the `rcx` reg. How should I count and also save the values in it before the stack push?

Comment: I removed the `rcx` `push` and `pop` and that still didn't work.

Comment: You don't need to push and pop rcx, rsi, rdi because they are volatile registers that can be altered by a function and don't need to be preserved. You can see that in [Figure 3.4: Register Usage in the SysV 64-bit ABI](https://www.uclibc.org/docs/psABI-x86_64.pdf). Beyond that the simplest fix is to change to `mov rcx, rsi   ; array length`
       `mov rsi, rdi    ; array address` . Since you are adding 32-bit ints you need to change `add rax, [rsi]` to `add eax, [rsi]` and add 4 to the address instead of 8 - change `add rsi, 8` to `add rsi, 4`.

Comment: The loop instruction can be inefficient (but it will work although it ties you to _RCX_. You can simplify the code by using _RDI_ for the pointer instead of _RSI_ that will eliminate an extra move. You also don't even need the stack frame so the `push rbp           
       mov rbp, rsp` at the start and `pop rbp` can be removed as well.

Comment: @Michael and Margaret thanks! it works. I'll just post the code below showing the changes!

Answer (score 1):

I followed the suggestions in the comments posted below the question and it works now, the cpp file is the same as above.

```
;nasm -f elf64 nasm_cpp.asm -o array.o
;g++ -m64 array.cpp array.o
;./a.out
global array               ; required for linker and NASM
section .text              ; start of the "CODE segment"

array:      
       push rbp           
       mov rbp, rsp        ; set up the rBP  

       mov rcx, rsi   ; array length
       mov rsi, rdi    ; array address

       xor rax, rax        ; clear the sum value       
lp:    add eax, [rsi]      ; fetch an array element
       add rsi, 4         ; move to another element
       loop lp             ; loop over all elements    

       pop rbp

       ret                 ; return to caller
```

Comment: Note your code won't work if the array length is zero. Whether that's a problem depends on your specifications.

Comment: I guess I could put a `jz outside_loop` conditional after `cmp rcx,0`?

Comment: There is also a `jecxz` instruction

Comment: Point taken! @Jester